# Azure kubernates Connection refused

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-aks

I am new at Kubernetes . I have Duende identity server deployed on azure Kubernetes the pod is running, however when I open via browser I get 502 Bad Gateway- ingress logs

6818062 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client
here is my deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-server-depl
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-server
        azure.workload.identity/use: "true"
      annotations:
        azure.workload.identity/inject-proxy-sidecar: "true"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: test-dev-service-account
      containers:
        - name: test-server
          image: test.azurecr.io/test-server
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9443          
          env:
            - name: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"
              value: "Development"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets
              mountPath: /app/secrets
              readOnly: true
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: workers-secret
      volumes:
        - name: secrets
          secret:
            secretName: test-identity-secret-appsettings
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-clusterip-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: test-server
  ports:
    - name: test-server-http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 980
    - name: test-worker-https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 9443
      protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    azure.workload.identity/client-id: 

  labels:
    azure.workload.identity/use: "true"
  name: test-dev-service-account
  namespace: default
```

I tried to open it via external IP but got ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

Here is my ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /test$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - test.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: tls-secret  
  rules:
  - host: test.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /test(.*)
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            service:
              name: test-clusterip-srv
              port:
                number: 80
```

Please help me to figure out

Comment: In your Service configuration (test-clusterip-srv), you've specified a targetPort of 980 for HTTP traffic and 9443 for HTTPS traffic. However, in your Deployment (test-server-depl), the container exposes port 9443. There's no mention of port 980, which could be the reason for the 502 Bad Gateway error if your application listens on 9443.

Comment: changed but still the same
```ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 980
            - name: https
              containerPort : 9443```

Comment: found the fix need to add following ingress annotation
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"

Comment: Great. You can post the same as answer for the SO community.

Comment: @Arthur It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, everything is fine except ingress, following needs to be added -     `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"`
here is full ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /test$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - galaxy-dev.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: tls-secret  
  rules:
  - host: test.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /test(.*)
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            service:
              name: test-clusterip-srv
              port:
                number: 80
            service:
              name: test-clusterip-srv
              port:
                number: 443
```